# gstreamer hlssink writes 60GB files

Tags: gstreamer, video-processing

I'm trying to cut 60-minute file to 60 1-minute files using this gstreamer pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location= video1.mp4 ! video/x-raw ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! hlssink target-duration=5 location=./video1/%05d.mp4
```

After 54 seconds it stops because a haven't got enough space on my disk.
File that gstreamer tryed to save is unplayable and weights 60 GB

Comment: You save raw, uncompressed video. That is a huge amount of data.

Comment: Well, how can I compress it? Need I use caps?